# Use of "and hence" for short conclusions

Tags: word-usage, relative-clauses

I wrote:

> Hydrochloric ions can influence the mutual solubility of IL and water **and hence** affect the extraction mechanism.

For several conclusions, I may use this construction. I would like to know how idiomatic is this structure, and what are other alternatives to use for such short conclusions in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

***thus*** would be my choice.

> Hydrochloric ions can influence the mutual solubility of IL and water, and thus affect the extraction mechanism.

Another way of framing the sentence would be,

> Hydrochloric ions can influence the mutual solubility of IL and water, thus affecting the extraction mechanism.

The variation of ***thereby*** provided by Tᴚoɯɐuo in their answer can be used in similar fashion. We also have ***therefore***.

In the case of ***in so doing***, the preferred way would be -

> Hydrochloric ions can influence the mutual solubility of IL and water, and in so doing, affect the extraction mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to **hence** would be **thereby** or **in so doing** or **thus**.

My recommendation would be **thereby**.

Comment: Thanks, which one needs "and" before it? I mean could you complete your answer by bringing an example of usage of each?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers describe valid responses. However, I think it is good to point out that using "and hence" is idiomatic and natural, and is not awkward.

My personal favorites would be to use "thus affect" or better yet "therefore affect." If I had to bet, I would guess that "therefore" would be the most common term.